# How to check if the first four characters of a string are A-G and the last 3 are numeric?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have been poking around with this and I feel it might be best if the string (AAAA-123 or AAA123) be split up into 2 strings and compared. I can ensure they are all numeric characters but making sure they are in the right format and I dont feel that I must be missing something.

```
   Name = txtfClass.getText();
        if((Name.length()==8)&&(Name.matches("[a-gA-G]-\\d{3}"))){
            checker(Name); 
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
```

That code wont work when Name = ABCD-123. What is it that I'm missing? If you are wondering here checker(Name) goes:

```
    public boolean checker(String name){
    CourseAbrv = name.substring(0, 4);
    System.out.println(CourseAbrv);
    return false;
}
```

It returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to `Name.matches("[A-G]{4}-\\d{3}")`. `[a-gA-G]` matches a Single character.

Note : This matches only capital `A-G`. You can use `a-g` instead of `A-G` to match only lowercase.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the answer by including to limit to A-G uppercase only and another with lowercase only. Pretty sure some will go here for those. :)